# What did Jesus mean by "mustard seed of faith"?

Tags: life-of-jesus, word-of-faith

What did Jesus mean when he talked about a mustard seed of faith?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! I hope you'll spend some time browsing the questions and answers here. This question is a little too broad and opinion-based for this site. Was there some particular group or denomination of Christians whose views on the parable you're interested in? For some tips on asking good questions, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) And for an introduction to this site and what it's all about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: If you want good answers, I suggest narrowing this question as @LeeWoofenden suggests. As is, the best answers you'll get will reference that the mustard seed is very small, so it's a reference to quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is Jesus meant by “mustard seed of faith”?**

The term "mustard seed" is illustrative of something very small. It is three times used of something that started small and became big and twice used to describe faith that is as small as mustard seed.

> Luke 17:5-10  And the apostles said unto the Lord, Increase our faith.
>   And the Lord said, If ye had faith as a grain of mustard seed, ye
>   might say unto this sycamine tree, Be thou plucked up by the root, and
>   be thou planted in the sea; and it should obey you.   But which of
>   you, having a servant plowing or feeding cattle, will say unto him by
>   and by, when he is come from the field, Go and sit down to meat?   And
>   will not rather say unto him, Make ready wherewith I may sup, and gird
>   thyself, and serve me, till I have eaten and drunken; and afterward
>   thou shalt eat and drink?   Doth he thank that servant because he did
>   the things that were commanded him? I trow not.   So likewise ye, when
>   ye shall have done all those things which are commanded you, say, We
>   are unprofitable servants: we have done that which was our duty to do.

When the disciples asked for more faith, Jesus gave them an illustration that they had some responsibility for the increase of their faith.